# How to make a get request in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, get-request

Alright so im making a Get request to this python script I made and i turned it into a basic API using PHP to send the request to as you can see below

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['GO']))
{
    shell_exec("C:Users/Bear/desktop/smtp/test-sender.py");
    echo"success";
}
```

?>

But whenever I go into the discord server and do the prefix and command it dosent work now here is the code I put in the discord bot to make a request to the API

```
import requests




 @client.command()
async def get(ctx, rec_email=int, message=int, int1=int):
    x = requests.GET(filename in os.listdir('./api.php'), parms ={"rec_email", "message", "int1"})
    await ctx.send('Sent!!!')
```

Whenever I do "!get email, message, number" it dosent work it dosent even say "Sent!!!!" what did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you searched for it? What did you find?

Comment: `(ctx, rec_email=int, message=int, int1=int)` Why are you defaulting the args to a type? try printing something before getting the request and check if the command is invoked

Answer (score 1):

The requests.get is made to send requests to an url, not to a file. I suggest to host that file on an url and then your bot sends a request to it.